# ORA-00904: "ADDRESS_USAGES"."AUS_PRO_REFNO": invalid identifier

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to run a select statement from two tables, the data that I want to return takes on 3-4 joins to achieve. I am getting the error

> ORA-00904: "ADDRESS_USAGES"."AUS_PRO_REFNO": invalid identifier

when both tables and columns exist. I have read the post relating to this error but given that I am just starting out I cant make head nor tail of them. Any suggestions (be gentle). SQL below TIA

```
select ins_srq_no, adr_line_all from inspections 
    join properties 
    on inspections.ins_pro_refno = properties.pro_propref
        join addresses 
        on properties.pro_propref = address_usages.aus_pro_refno
            join address_usages 
            on address_usages.aus_pro_refno = addresses.adr_refno
               where fsc.address_usages.end_date is null;
```

Comment: I've added an answer which covers why you're getting the error, and has a stab at suggesting a corrected query - but I can't be certain about the latter part without understanding your table definitions. It's best to include cut-down table definitions (including any foreign keys) when asking questions about SQL errors.

Comment: Thanks Jo, I should add that the column adr_line_all is located within a table called "addresses" I also realise that this needs to be included but lacking the knowledge to do so

Answer (score 0):

This `on` clause is incorrect, because you haven't yet joined to the address_usages table: `on properties.pro_propref = address_usages.aus_pro_refno`. This is causing Oracle to throw the error you're seeing; it's not about the table or column not existing, it's the fact that within that query, that identifier is invalid because you haven't yet joined to the table.

At a guess (I can't be 100% sure without seeing your table structures and foreign keys), you need to join addresses back to properties. If so, the query should look something like this:

```
select ins_srq_no, adr_line_all
from inspections 
inner join properties 
  on inspections.ins_pro_refno = properties.pro_propref
inner join addresses 
  on properties.pro_propref = addresses.[column name of FK to properties]
inner join address_usages 
  on address_usages.aus_pro_refno = addresses.adr_refno
where fsc.address_usages.end_date is null;
```